# [Laravel model]How can I update when a specific duplicated data is existed. [Laravel]

Tags: laravel

I have a table .

```
Books
`id(PK),name, genre, publish_date(DATE_TIME)`
```

I would like to make it update When a record with same genre and publish_date exists.

`id(PK),name, genre, publish_date(DATE_TIME)`

for example

1,iq84,fiction,2022-04-11

is existed.

when
1q84,fiction,2022-04-11
is saved then 2,1q84,fiction,2022-04-11 is created.

I would like to make it "1,1q84,fiction,2022-04-11"

How can I fix it? How should I change the table structure?

Save function

```
$book = new Book;
$book->name = "1q84";
$book->genre = 1;//fiction
$book->publish_date = '2022-04-01';
$book->save();
```

```
$bookStore = new bookStore;
$bookStore->bookId = $book->id;
```

Comment: Just try with [updateOrCreate](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#upserts). It is a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [updateOrCreate](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#upserts) method.
for your example you can do it like this :

```
Book::updateOrCreate(
    ['gener' => 1,'publish_date' => '2022-04-01'],
    ['name' => '1q84']
);
```

Comment: Thank you for answering.
When it uses updateOrCreate then another problem happen. How intermediate table should get the id of the record of the book.